# Setting an attribute to 0 if a checkbox is checked in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a db column called starting_pt that is a decimal.
I want a checkbox, that if checked, will set starting_pt = 0.0

I have set-up the a virt attr in my Model and added it to the accesible's

```
attr_acessor :reset
attr_accessible :reset
```

I've set up

```
before_create :reset_starting_pt, :if => :reset?

def reset?
    @reset == "1"
end 

def reset_starting_pt
    @starting_pt = 0.0
end
```

This is assuming that a checked checkbox is equal to "1" and an unchecked is equal to "0".

This solution is not working.  Any guidance anyone can provide on how to do do this would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm testing wrong? Suggestions on how to test this with rspec, in the console?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a setter method for the reset which when supplied with "0" will reset your @starting_pt instance variable.

```
def reset= val
  @starting_pt = 0.0 if 0 == val.to_i
end
```